# Unity Accessing method of 3d Text/TextMesh to other script

Tags: unity-game-engine

i made a script and attached it to 3d text, now my problem is accessing the method from that script to other class

[image: my class]

[image: the class that i want to access]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` with 's' in the `Object`. Use `FindGameObjectWithTag` without 's' in the `Object`. The version of this function with 's' is for array but **g** is not defined as array.

That line of code should be:

```
g = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tagText No");
```

Answer (score 2):

[FindGameObjectsWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) returns an array of gameobjects (`GameObject[]`), and you are trying to assign it into a `GameObject`.

Use `FindWithTag` instead :

```
g = GameObject.FindWithTag("tagText no");
```